# Distinguishing between ArrayList#remove() methods

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an ArrayList of integers, as such;

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(8);
list.add(20);
list.add(50);
```

I also have a variable, that is set to a random item from that ArrayList. I want to remove the item in the variable from the arraylist, so I tried this;

```
list.remove(var);
```

However, it assumes that because `var` is an integer, it tries to get the index at the location of `var` instead of searching for and removing it. But because every item in the list is larger than the size of it, it always gives an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. Is there a way to force Java to attempt to use the proper remove method?

Comment: Pass an `Integer` reference.

Comment: How do I pass an Integer reference?

Comment: Declare `var` as an `Integer`. Or cast it within the method invocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an `Integer` - your main options are:

```
Integer valueToRemove = 8;
list.remove(valueToRemove);

int anotherOne = 20;
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(anotherOne));

int andFinally = 50;
list.remove((Integer) andFinally);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call add(8), it is actually autoboxed so the actual call is add(new Integer(8)).  That doesn't happen on the remove() call because there's actually a remove() call that takes an int as an argument.  The solution is to create the Integer object yourself instead of relying on autoboxing:  `list.remove(new Integer(var))`.

Comment: Don't call `new Integer`. Ever. This is almost as bad as calling `new String`.

Comment: It's all going to result in the same bytecode, anyway.

Comment: Nope. `new Integer` creates a new instance of `Integer`. `Integer.valueOf` will (usually, depending on size) take an `Integer` from the pool.

Comment: In theory, it can be different in that way; however, note that the lookup from the pool may be more expensive than creating a new Integer, as it usually is with Strings.  In practice, the recompiler is likely to optimize it away in both cases.